# Count how many times a picture is downloaded from the server

Tags: website

How can I tell how many times a picture has been downloaded from my server? I use directadmin, but I can also use cpanel if this is easier.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

directadmin should have a web stats tool of some sort this will tell you

Answer (score 6):

grep the apache logs. That'd be what i'd do anyhow.

Comment: grep filename.jpg /var/log/httpd/access.log | wc -l

Comment: How do I do this?